# AWK command executed with out error but not modifying the file

Tags: command-line, awk

I am applying awk command on a file but this file is not modifying. can any one suggest why this is happening?

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}; {if($692=="6") sub($690,"9");print $0;}' abc.txt >efg.txt
```

Note: each line contains around 1000 characters.

Comment: the command is working when the no. of characters is less than 100

Comment: What command are you exactly using? Also parameter etc. please

Comment: Copy the command from terminal, click "Edit" button on your questions, and paste the command into question.

Comment: @SuBho were you trying to modify `abc.txt` file ? Because that's not how your command reads.

Comment: trying to execute the command in unix box...............just as a normal unix command

Comment: my goal is to keep both the file the source file abc.txt and the modified version of abc.txt(efg.txt)

Comment: if abc.txt contains "123456" then after the execution of the command i want efg.txt with "1234569" and content of abc.txt will remain unchanged

Comment: Use `gawk`, not unix `awk`

Comment: @SuBho well, I understand what you're trying to do, and I've tested the command with shorter string. Double check the 692nd character, maybe you've miscalculated and "6" is actually is 693rd or other.  The idea works, but what you're testing in the if statement might not be correct

Comment: @RomeoNinov on Ubuntu `awk` is `gawk`, it's a symlink, at least in newer OS versions. If it's older release like 14.04 , it might still be shipping with `mawk`, but regardless of the fact, the command is still supposed to work all the same

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, I have my doubts OP ask about Linux. Because such behavior is typical for UNIX awk

Comment: nothing worked. but when the no. of characters in a line is less then it is working fine

Comment: @RomeoNinov  If you mean OP is using different OS, yes, maybe they should ask on different site, [unix.se] for example. But if it is indeed Ubuntu, I don't really see what could be wrong here. The command works in my tests

Comment: @SuBho so  your character indeed could be in different place. `$692` isn't below awk's maximum, so it should be able to handle replacement if it's indeed in right place

Comment: I think I know what's wrong. Brb, writing answer

Comment: @SuBho, remove semicolon after BEGIN block

Comment: Good question. Really threw me for a loop here. It was syntactically correct, but not proper for what OP is trying to do. I posted answer. In future, double check the syntax of the functions you're trying to use

Answer (score 0):

#### What is wrong

The key issue is that you're using `sub()` incorrectly. `sub()` is supposed to substitute based on pattern match (that's the important part!). Proper syntax is:

```
sub(regular_expression,replacement,substring)
```

What you're doing is `sub($692,"9")`, so you're telling it to replace first occurrence of the same thing that you see in field number 692, but that first occurrence may be way way way before in the line.

Here's an example:

```
$ echo "1253456" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""};{if($4==3) sub($6,"@");print}'                                                                               
12@3456
```

This literally takes whatever in the 6th field (which is number 5) and removes first occurrence of that thing. Same as what your command was doing.

#### What should actually be done

To replace a specific field, you don't need `sub()`, just assign to the field directly.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}; {if($692==6) $690="9";print}' abc.txt >efg.txt
```

Notice that I also removed `$0` from `print` because calling `print` itself already assumes `$0` by default